# EditText not scrollable inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` inside which is an `EditText` which is set to scroll vertically. But it does not scrolls. Instead the whole layout scrolls, Whenever i try to scroll the `EditText`.
Below is the code -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#3bb9ff"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Title"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="#3bb9ff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
   />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newTodoText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="7"
     android:hint="Write something"
     android:scrollbars = "vertical" >
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Add" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The EditText with id "newTodoText" is in question here.

Answer (score 107):

```
EditText EtOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
EtOne.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.EditText01) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes really..This code worked ..Straight and simple...Awesome Amsheer...Great Thanks

Comment: Top notch answer but one question, is it possible to only register this touch interception(scroll the edit text) when there is enough content in the edit text for it to be scrollable?

Comment: @Jack.Ramsden in that case you would wrap the whole content inside the onTouch, except the return statment inside a if conditions, that gets the EditText length end checks of its bigger than a certains amount of characters (50 for example!).

Comment: is it necessary to remove the disallow intercept on ACTION_UP? I thought this is naturally reset at the end of the gesture.

Answer (score 18):

```
mEdtText1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mScrlMain.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

// change hear mEdtText1 with your edit text object and also change mScrlMain with your scroll view object they work definitely.

Comment: This worked great for me.  I could not get Amsheer's to work. Thank you!

Comment: I like this clean and neat way.

Answer (score 7):

you should use NestedScrollView class. This class support child scrolling inside parent scrolling. This class can be a child or a parent.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView         
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#d6d8d9">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="512"
                android:text=" your content"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_below="@id/ll_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#d6d8d9">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="your content"
                android:maxLines="512"/>    
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>       
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: none of other answers worked, but yours is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

This will make your entire layout scrollable.

For setting your edittext scrollable add `android:scrollbars="vertical"`  to your **edittext**

In your code its already written

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newTodoText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="7"
     android:hint="Write something"
     android:scrollbars = "vertical" >
```

Remove the  from code.It will work fine

Answer (score 2):

**Use this Code Its Working**

**in Xml**

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

**in Pragraming**

```
et_feedback.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                if (view.getId() == R.id.et_feedback) {
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
noteEdit.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance();


    noteEdit.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            noteEdit.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            return false;
        }


    });
```

Comment: I think something is wrong in what you wrote. The `ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()` isn't used...

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do so is mentioned below with some description

```
            myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  //Register a callback to be invoked when a touch event is sent to this view.
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {     
//Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows listeners to get a chance to respond before the target view.
                mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have set `ScrollView` as your parent most layout. That's reason
  your whole layout gets scrolled.
- As, far as your EditText is concerned, you have used
  `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` which means **if the EditText
  grows** a vertical srollBar will appear. You will get the scrollbar and scrolling effect 
  only if edittext has data high enough..

Hope this helps...

Comment: Even if the data is high enough,the EditText is not scrollable. how can i make it scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

**XML code**

```
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
```

**Use below code for Kotlin**

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (v.id == R.id.editText) {
            v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem inside a bottom sheet that was swiping to close, I suspect this will work in general though:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
fun View.blockAllAncestorsInterceptingTouch() {
    setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        false
    }
}
```

The suppress Lint is legitimate, there is no need to call performClick if you always return false.

Answer (score -2):

You have set "Scroll View" to your parent - this means it scrolls the whole layout.

If you want to scroll a particular "Edit text" then you have to put another Scroll view to that edit text.